# Give access to view or table?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I want to give an external user (new login) read access to part of the data model from my Database. The user will copy the data model and content from my Database, and then integrate that into their own database.

Should I give the user a read access to the actual tables, or should I create views for the Tables they need to see?
If a View is the way to go, can I put unrelated tables in the same View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In almost ALL cases, YES, use a view. Then you can have multiple joined tables, as may be required, whereto you would not have to give any access

Comment: I can't join all the tables that need to be accessed, since this includes unrelated tables(no keys to connect them), and I want to avoid making a view for every Table - or should I?

Comment: No, you will need 1 view per "result set".  If you need multiple result sets from multiple (joined or unjoined) tables / result sets, then you must create a view for each.